# declare plugin in a variable in the view section extjs mvc

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

i have done cell editing/ row editing using row editing plugin. But for some condition  i need to declare the plugin in the view's view section as

```
var editing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2,

pluginId:'celledit'
        });
```

then use the plugin as

```
plugins: [
   editing
],
```

unfortunately i am not allowed to do this...is there any way that i can store the plugin in a variable and then use it because i have some logic for when should i activate row editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin has `enable()` and `disable()` methods, perhaps that is what you are going to use when you need to "activate row editing". Given that the code is within `initComponent`, it comes to something like:

```
this.editing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        });
this.editing.disable();
```

and then

```
this.plugins = [
   this.editing
];
```

Comment: OK, does `this.editing` wherever you're accessing it actually point to the plugin instance? In other words, will `this.editing instanceof Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` evaluate to `true`?
You can also access the plugin using say `grid.getPlugin('pluginId')`

Comment: this is working for me                                              var grid=Ext.getCmp('mylist');                                       var editor=grid.getPlugin('celledit');